# When to use a ManyToMany field over a ForeignKey?

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, many-to-many

Consider that we have two Django models, Question and Answer.
A question can have many answers to it, but an answer can have only one question related to it.
We can model the relationship as:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    text     = models.CharField(...)
    answers  = models.ManyToManyField('Answer')

class Answer(models.Model):
    text     = models.CharField(...)
```

We can also model it as:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    text     = models.CharField(...)

class Answer(models.Model):
    text     = models.CharField(...)
    question = models.ForeignKey('Question')
```

Django managers allow us to follow both ForeignKey and ManyToManyField backwards.
What model structure should we use?

Comment: Since you explicitly state the answer could only belong to one question, why would you even consider many to many?

Answer (score 2):

`one-to-many` of course. You could achieve the same thing using many-to-many relationship but you'll complicate things a lot and you'll pay for a performance hit.

Think of it from a database modelling point of view (forget the ORM). Why would you want to do: `question -> many-to-many-manager -> answers` instead of having: `question -> answers`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Question(models.Model):
    text     = models.CharField(...)
    answers  = models.ManyToManyField('Answer')
```

Above models say an **Answer** can have many Questions and a **Question** can have many answers.
Partially wrong and partially correct.

> Many to Many relationships: You have many siblings and your one of a
>   sibling has many siblings.

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    text     = models.CharField(...)
    question = models.ForeignKey('Question')
```

Now, this model says an **Question** can have many Answers and an **Answer** can have one question only.

> One to Many relationships: A person can have many numbers and but a number can't  assigned to many persons

In my opinion, it is more correct.