# Django models asymmetric relationship

Tags: django, django-models

With following Django models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    bestbookaccordingtome=models.????(Author,null=True, blank=True, default = None)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.OnetoOneField(Author)
```

I want the classic relationship each book has one author (only).

But I also want to be able to assign a chosen book to author (my favourite book of this author for example).

I tried a foreign key but django didn't like it.
Any python clean way to do it?

Comment: if you're looking to model a user's choice for an author's favourite book, then I really feel that this field should live on a many-to-many relationship between users and authors. think of it this way: Your favourite work by Oscar Wilde might be The Importance of Being Earnest, while for me it definitely has to be The Picture of Dorian Gray. get it?

Comment: In this case, I will be the only one to choose, users won't have their word on it.

Comment: by the way, if each book has only one author, shouldn't I use foreignkey?

Comment: yes both you `author` and `bestbookaccordingtome` fields should be modeled as `ForeignKeyField`s. When you say "Django didn't like it", what do you mean exactly? Could you be more specific :)

Comment: sorry, error is :Reverse query name for 'Company.random' clashes with field name 'Book.author'. HINT: Rename field 'Book.author, or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'Company.random'.   I renamed the field and it seems to work

Comment: As the error says; add `related_name` argument to the field. In your case e.g add to Book.author something like this `related_name="books"`. Should be unique.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use a ManyToMany field over a ForeignKey?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35962219/when-to-use-a-manytomany-field-over-a-foreignkey)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    bestbookaccordingtome = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, related_name='best_book_according_to_me')
```

Also, if you need to specify extra fields in your n-m model, you can use [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) to indicate the name of the model.

Hope it helps!